# Firebase Database Rules private nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm doing a groceryItem app where users can add items and only should see their own items.
I add my items by using `childByAutoId` and get unique key entries for each item (see picture #1).
[image]

Each item hast got 3 properties. `addedByUser` is the UID of an authenticated user and of course a name and the quantity.

I have problems setting the rules so that only users can see their own items. My current rules look like this (see picture #2).
[image]

If I log in with another user he can read all items. So my question is:
How I can make items readable for the users who created them?

I think I have a gap between `items` and `addedByUser` because I have the `childByAutoId` between. If you have any solutions or tips how I can structure this in a better way, pls feel free to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think i found the first failure. ".read and .write rules work from top-down, with shallower rules overriding deeper rules" is explained at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $addedByUser is probably in the wrong spot in this example, as it is not a "nested child" of the items, but an attribute of a child item.  I would suggest (not having tested this) that you would be looking for something along the lines of:

```
"items": {
  "$item": {
    ".read": "data.child('addedByUser').val() === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

This is lifted from the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_you_rules):

With data:

```
{
  "messages": {
    "message0": {
      "content": "Hello",
      "timestamp": 1405704370369
    },
    "message1": {
      "content": "Goodbye",
      "timestamp": 1405704395231
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

The rules could be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        // only messages from the last ten minutes can be read
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",

        // new messages must have a string content and a number timestamp
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['content', 'timestamp']) && newData.child('content').isString() && newData.child('timestamp').isNumber()"
      }
    }
```

}
}

This will prevent the incorrect user from reading someone else's (singular) item, and in your example would prevent user SZ825V... from performing a read on "items/-KKTDD...", however if user SZ825V were to perform a read on "items", then the read would fail entirely, because the user is trying to read their own documents and someone else's as well.  This is an important concept in firebase with the rules behaving in an atomic way - that is, if one part of the read fails, the entire read does.  Another way of putting this is that the rules do not act as a filter.
If this is the functionality you are seeking, it may be required to rearrange your structure.  An example could be as follows:

```
{
  "users": {
    "abcdef-user-id": {
      "items": {
        "fjeiwofjewio": {
           "name": "apple",
           "qty": "23"
        }
      }
    },
    "ghijkl-user-id": {
      "items": {
        "regrewgreh": {
          "name": "passionfruit",
          "qty": "18"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and security rules might be:

```
.. {
     "users": {
       "$userId": {
          ".read": "auth.uid === $userId"
       }
     }
   }
```

The above approach assumes you only want to allow a user to read the items in their user own data tree, is that no-one else would be able to see any other users' items.  If you did want other users to see some of the other users' items, then a different approach again would be required, which would be another SO question.

Comment: ref.child("items").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            
            var newItems = [Item]()
            for item in snapshot.children {
                print(item)
                let item = Item(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newItems.append(item)
            }

In my iOS app im calling observeEvent on this ref.
Now i cant read anything :(

Comment: That is because of the atomic nature of firebase permissions.  If you read the "items" list and any of the reads fail (ie because you are trying to read an item belonging to another user), then the whole read fails, thus items returns nothing.  The rules do not act as filters.  My answer related to being able to read a user's item and preventing other users from reading, not trying to read the list of items in its entirety.  A different structure may be appropriate, which I will add in the answer.